# How to use querySelectorAll to get direct children

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api, child-nodes

I know you can do this:

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll(".list > a");
```

but what if you have a selection already and you want to get every direct child?

```
var list = document.querySelector(".list"); //say you can't change this line
var sel = list.querySelector("& > a"); //sass selector doesn't work
```

I know this can be done by checking on the `childNodes` list... but if querySelectorAll could be used, it would be much easier. I tried using `("& > a")` and only `("> a")` and didn't work... Got any ideas?

Comment: `list.children` gets you all children, then just filter on tagName

Comment: `var sel = document.querySelectorAll(".list")[0].getElementsByTagName('a');`

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: The question is about *direct children*. That code would find any `a` anywhere in the first `.list`, not just when it's a direct child.